# How does this work in terms of data variability in bytes?

Tags: swift

```
let keyData: NSData! = (keyString as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as NSData!
```

1. What would keyData amount to in terms of `bytes` if `keyString = "1234567890000000000000000"`?
2. What can I do to see the value of `keyData` or print it to the console?
3. Also, how can I get the `keyString` back from `keyData` in `Swift`?

Can someone please explain what is going on in here in this expression? I cannot seem to get my head around it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `NSString` and `NSData`? Just do `let keyData = keyString.data(using: .utf8)`.

Comment: Why not iterate the data and print the bytes? Then you can see what you are getting.

Comment: @rmaddy It is not by choice. This is one expression from a complete working program and the value of `keyData` will go to `CCCrypt` method from `CommonCrypto` API.

Comment: @rmaddy I am relatively new to `Swift` could you provide a pseudo snippet or actual code to help with it? I am only concerned about the difference in data bytes.

Comment: Is this a debugging question? Or a Data<->String conversion one? The question seems a little bit broad.

Comment: @Cristik It is rather a Data<->String conversion question.Please suggest edits so that I can make it more focused.

Comment: Questions #2 and #3 are likely to already have answers here on SO, so I would remove them, and focus on the main question (#1), which you could expand with more details about what exactly you're trying to find out about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of `bytes` will depend on the `encoding` you used to convert `string` to `data`. Below are the answers to each question

1) `print(keyData.length)`

2) `print(String(data: keyData as Data, encoding: .utf8)!)`

3) `let string = String(data: keyData as Data, encoding: .utf8)!`